# Output categories of related entry within grid field?

Tags: categories, relationships, grid

I have a grid field (EE 2.7.2), within which is a relationship field. I want to output the categories associated with the related item within the grid field. Is this possible? I thought this might work, but it might be a step too far, tag-nesting wise:

```
{organisation}                                     
    {organisation:related_organisation:title} {!-- outputs related entry title, yay! --}

    {!-- this doesn't output anything --}
    {organisation:related_organisation:categories}
        {category_id}
    {/organisation:related_organisation:categories}                                                                         
{/organisation}
```

Comment: Perhaps I need to unpack the above: organisation is a grid field; related_organisation is a relationship field within that grid where the editor can select an organisation from a list of entries. I want to grab the categories associated with that organisation entry (if possible)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
{organisation}                                     
    {organisation:related_organisation:title}
    {organisation:related_organisation:categories}
        {organisation:related_organisation:category_id}
    {/organisation:related_organisation:categories}                                                                         
{/organisation}
```

Note the change, from:

```
{category_id}
```

to:

```
{organisation:related_organisation:category_id}
```

You must remember to reference the parents when nesting.