# trying to get category_url_title from a relationship in a grid field

Tags: categories, relationships, grid

Having a strange issue with grid, categories and relationships. On my site i have a channel with products and services. On the services pages i need my client to be able to select related products to be shown, so i used a grid field with relationships to products.
The products are categorised, so i want to see the category_url_title in the url.

I checked [this thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/output-categories-of-related-entry-within-grid-field) and followed that approach however i'm not getting this to output anything. (http://www.site.com/producten//systeemoefeningen/ for what should be http://www.site.com/producten/oefenen/systeemoefeningen/)

```
{services_grid_products}
  <li><a href="/producten/category/
      {services_grid_products:product}
         {services_grid_products:product:categories}
             {services_grid_products:product:categories:category_url_title}
         {/services_grid_products:product:categories}
      {/services_grid_products:product}/{url_title}/" 
      title="
      {services_grid_products:product}
          {services_grid_products:product:title}
      {/services_grid_products:product}"> 
      {services_grid_products:product}
          {services_grid_products:product:title}
      {/services_grid_products:product}</a></li>
{/services_grid_products}
```

I know i can do this with an embed too, however i'm trying to avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: Try taking the prefix off of the {category_url_title} variable, like this: {services_grid_products:product:categories}{category_url_title}{/services_grid_products:product:categories}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edited version (and just saw that Kevin Cupp beat me to it!):
Just tested this and only needed to use {category_url_title}.

So try:

```
{services_grid_products:product:categories}
    {category_url_title}
{/services_grid_products:product:categories}
```

Comment: nope... doesn't work

Comment: See edited version.

Comment: I wish it was that easy... doesn't return anything...

Comment: Oh Bollocks.. content editors removed the categories... you guys were right thanks!