# Relationship nested in Grid - how to get content

Tags: relationships, grid

I've got a grid where one of the cells is a relationship field. I'm unable to get the relationship to output any content.

My grid field is {related_quote} the cell with the relationship is "quote_entry" and the content field inside the related entry is "quote_copy"

My code as it stands now.

```
{related_quote}
<div class="quote_bubble_text">
    {related_quote:quote_entry}
        {related_quote:quote_entry:quote_copy} Yo something here
    {related_quote:quote_entry} 
    {!--yo yo yo--}
</div>
{/related_quote}
```

The only thing I can see is "Yo something here" which indicates taht I've got the relationship working as it's processing copy inside. But can't figure out how to get the actual quote_copy field to render.

Comment: Looks like you aren't closing your {related_quote:quote_entry} tag (the second one doesn't have a /). If you do that, does it work?

Comment: seems similar to my issue: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19664/trying-to-get-category-url-title-from-a-relationship-in-a-grid-field/19754#19754 have a look!

Comment: That is such a freaking noob mistake. Thanks Kevin all good now.